# Best way to remove empty query strings from an API request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

In my react app I am tasked with sending multiple GET requests, sometimes with some optional filter params attached. Additionally I'm storing the params in my redux store so that they are able to stack on subsequent requests. Here's the problem: There are times when I'll clear the values of a param but since their keys are still saved to my store I'll get requests sent out like this:

```
/restaurants/?search=&state_id=2
```

Notice how the `search` param value is empty (as expected). I was wondering what would be the best approach in removing these type of lingering params? I looked into lodash's `_.omitBy` combined with `_.isEmpty` but this throws a sort of false positive in dealing with numeric values like pagination.

```
_.omitBy(params, ._isEmpty);
```

I didn't think that providing *how* exactly the params are via react/redux was necessary stored but am happy to provide it if it helps.

**Note:** I'm using axios and passing my params in as an object as opposed to a string:

```
axios.get('restaurants', {
  params
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering your params are stored in an object (as you mentioned in your latest edit), you can just remove properties containing empty strings:

```js
const params = {
  search: "",
  state_id: 2
};

for (const key of Object.keys(params)) {
  if (params[key] === "") {
    delete params[key];
  }
}

console.info(params);
```

This alternative has the advantage of being short and easy to maintain.

But for those with a string containing all params already serialized, it's easy to do using regular expressions:

```js
function removeEmptyParams(query) {
  return query.replace(/[^=&]+=(?:&|$)/g, "");
}

const testQuery = "f=1&search=&state_id=2&foo=&bar=12";
console.info(removeEmptyParams(testQuery));
```

Also very simple and easy to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

The best and easiest way is to use a Spread Object literal on every optional param,
like this

```
params:{

   ...( CONDITION && {param_key: param_value}),
   ...( this.state_id != null && {state_id: this.state_id})
}
```

If condition is TRUE, the encapsulated key:value pair will be unwrapped, if condition is false , there will be no empty value or key.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to parse that manually. Split on the `&` then split on the `=` and check if there's a value based on the length of the split - remove accordingly from there. If you're comfortable with regex you can check if there are values after the `=` instead of splitting.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is a little crude, but it works. Let's assume your query params are stored in a Map, something like:

```
const params = {
 foo: 'bar',
 bang: 0,
 buzz: '' // this value has been removed from your store
}
```

You could create an array of keys from your params Map, filter out the items that don't have a value and then join them all back together as query params.

```
const queryString = Object.keys(params).map(filter => {
    if (params[filter] || Number.isInteger(params[filter])) {
      return `${filter}=${params[filter]}`;
    }
    return null;
  }).filter(item => item).join('&');
```

Which would result in `foo=bar&bang=0`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there is a possibility to use package like "queryString". It removes empty search params form url string

```
import queryString from 'query-string';

const queryParams = queryString.stringify({ filters, sort: sortParams, offset: PRODUCT_OFFSET, limit: PRODUCT_LIMIT });
const urlProductList = `${BASE_URL}/country/${countryCode}/group/${groupID}/product?${queryParams}`;
```